# How to suppress default outputs on serverless cloudformation yml?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless

I'm using  serverless-stack-output to save my serverless output to a file with some custom values that I setup. Works well, but serverless has some other default outputs such as these:

```
FunctionQualifiedArn (one for each function)
ServiceEndpoint
ServerlessDeploymentBucketName
```

I don't want these to show on my file, how to disable serverless/cloudformation from outputting them?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at this stage.
I've dug through the code and there's no switch that to suppress outputs.
Unfortunate, as I have the exact same requirement.